# How to pass a command line argument from a cpp file and use it in a shell script?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

So, I have to create a cpp file that uses my script to search for someones name. I'm pretty new to this so I don't know much but this is what I currently have. Also I have to use system(). Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    system("./findName.sh" + argv[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You included `<string>`. Why not create a `std::string` with the full command you want to pass to `std::system`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in C++, string literals (such as `"./findName.sh"`) are not `std::string`, but pointers. For pointers, addition has another meaning than string concatenation.

You can create a `std::string` and use it to perform the concatenation:

```
    std::string scriptName = "./findName.sh";
    std::string command = scriptName + " " + argv[1];

    system(command.c_str());
```

Don't forget to check the size of `argc` to make sure there is an argument.

Comment: I tried this but it is telling me that the command line arguments are not equal to 1, (I wrote this in the shell script)

Comment: @Cholo This should be your main function.

Comment: It is in my main function, but it is saying the message, like if it didn't receive my argument

Comment: also it tells me "./findName.sh: 1: [: 1: unexpected operator"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::system` or `boost::process` for this purposes.